# How can I make a image to scroll down or up when I scroll down or up page?

Tags: html, css

How can I make an image scroll down or up when I scroll the page down or up?

I have HTML on a page and an image in that page.

When I scroll down the page, I want the image to get down in the same time when I scroll down the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're talking about a distinct image element..you can do it a number of ways, the easiest (not best necessarily) would be to set its `position` to `fixed`

Have a look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3n4Df/)

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `position:fixed` into your css on the image you want to follow the page

Answer (score 0):

Give `position:fixed` in css to the image

Here is the Demo for the same:

**http://jsfiddle.net/vR756/**